# Docker compose file memory, cpu limits

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying use memory and CPU in docker-compose file.

I get below error code:

> ```
> The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: 
> Unsupported config option for services.web: 'resources'
> ```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is below

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - "./app:/home"
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"       
        resources:
            limits:
                cpus: '0.001'
                memory: 512M
```

How can I use CPU, memory with in docker-compose?

Comment: Post `docker-compose version` please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Docker compose resources](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) were introduced in file format version 3, which needs docker-compose 1.13 or newer. Chances are you are using an older version:. Check the output of:

```
docker-compose version
```

See the [upgrade guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

The OP uses docker-compose 1.12, which does not yet support version 3.

> solved: I use version: '2' instead of version: '3' in docker-composer file and ı use `mem_limit` instead of `resources`

Comment: **docker-compose version output:**
``docker-compose version 1.12.0, build b31ff33
docker-py version: 2.2.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016``

Comment: @AdnanBilaç Then try using the exact same space tabulation as the one described in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources, just to check if this is not a format issue.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, Problem solved but ı use version: '2' instead of version: '3' in docker-composer file and ı use mem_limit instead of resources

Comment: @AdnanBilaç That means version 3 is only supported with docker 1.13 or more. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Espacially note the "note" with the headline "Looking for options to set resources on non swarm mode containers?" in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources which contains a link to a github discussion about introducing limit for non-swarm mode in compose files v3: Here we learn that v3 was introduced espacially for swarm mode and v2 will be supported in future.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Docker Compose v.3 configs and running `docker-compose up` mode, then this can be useful.

This is not documented anywhere in docker-compose, but you can pass any valid system call `setrlimit` option in `ulimits`.

So, you can specify in `docker-compose.yaml`

`ulimits:
  as:
    hard: 130000000
    soft: 100000000`

memory size is in bytes. After going over this limit your process will get memory allocation exceptions, which you may or may not trap.